# Multiple views folders with Express and Handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I need to register multiple views folders using Express and express-handlebars. Is it posible?

I have this structure:

```
/project/
    /admin/
        /views/
        /server/
    /webapp/
        /views/
        /server/
    /common/
    /node_modules/
```

And I need that when I render a view in a route I be able to access to one of these folders views /admin/views/ or /webapp/views/.

Comment: For this functionality, you need to do authentication first, then you need to check if admin logged in the application then redirect admin to another views  & client logged in the application then redirect admin to another view...I don't know why you have created separation for that.

Comment: I want to have a separated folders to organize better my app, I know that I can do this, but that's not the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from express version 4 you can do this by passing an array of directories `app.set(name, value)` like this:

```
app.set('views', [
  path.join(__dirname, 'app/index'),
  path.join(__dirname, 'app/error'),
]);
```

**Naming conflict:**

Be careful when you doing this so you don't get naming conflict. For example if you have  two files both named `error.ejs` one inside `app/index` and the other inside `app/error`, express will serve the one inside in `app/index` since the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set) state:

> the views are looked up in the order they occur in the array.